# Duplicate Keys in tMySQLOutput Error but no original key stored in database. How to resolve in Talend DI?

Tags: mysql, duplicates, talend

I have a talend job which reads a db table into a tMap and stores the result in another db table. The destination table is set to "insert" only and before running the job I drop the destination table so its always starting fresh. I have an error logger to handle problems writing to the destination table

I process about 150k rows and it kicks 41k of those saying there was a duplicate entry for key PRIMARY.

While I do expect there to be some duplicates when I check the error logger there are rows where a duplicate key was detected but no matching value is found in the destination table.

Any ideas what might be going on? Its hard to understand as there is also error handling on the tMap component but it seems to be an issue actually writing to the db table once approved rows are sent to it from tMap

For what its worth. I using Talend DI 5.6.1 reading and writing to the same database schema but different tables on MySQL db 5.6.17

Incase its useful I have a number of subjobs that use the same source and destinations but just refine the city value a bit differently on each execution
**Source Schema**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema dbmsId="mysql_id">
    <column comment="" default="" key="true" label="Column22"
        length="50" nullable="false" originalDbColumnName="Column22"
        originalLength="0" pattern="" precision="0"
        talendType="id_String" type="VARCHAR"/>
    <column comment="" default="" key="false" label="city" length="50"
        nullable="true" originalDbColumnName="city" originalLength="0"
        pattern="" precision="0" talendType="id_String" type="VARCHAR"/>
    <column comment="" default="" key="false" label="CountryCode"
        length="3" nullable="true" originalDbColumnName="CountryCode"
        originalLength="0" pattern="" precision="0"
        talendType="id_String" type="VARCHAR"/>
    <column comment="" default="" key="false" label="svc_area_code"
        length="20" nullable="true" originalDbColumnName="svc_area_code"
        originalLength="0" pattern="" precision="0"
        talendType="id_String" type="VARCHAR"/>
</schema>
```

**Destination Schema**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema dbmsId="mysql_id">
    <column comment="" default="" key="true" label="Column22"
        length="50" nullable="true" originalDbColumnName="Column22"
        originalLength="0" pattern="" precision="0"
        talendType="id_String" type="VARCHAR"/>
    <column comment="" default="" key="false" label="city" length="50"
        nullable="true" originalDbColumnName="city" originalLength="0"
        pattern="" precision="0" talendType="id_String" type="VARCHAR"/>
    <column comment="" default="" key="false" label="CountryCode"
        length="3" nullable="true" originalDbColumnName="CountryCode"
        originalLength="3" pattern="" precision="0"
        talendType="id_String" type="VARCHAR"/>
    <column comment="" default="" key="false" label="svc_area_code"
        length="20" nullable="true" originalDbColumnName="svc_area_code"
        originalLength="20" pattern="" precision="0"
        talendType="id_String" type="VARCHAR"/>
</schema>
```

Comment: you have to give more details about your job here.. i guess you have tmysqlinput-->tmap-->tmysqloutput component...what are you doing in tmap? in tmysqloutput schema what you have defined as your keys as this is what talend will use to check if row exists in DB table or not before inserting....

Comment: check are you getting duplicate key in source? i think you are not committing changes on per record and then it will try to commit duplicate keys.

Comment: Hi garpitmzn thats exactly what I'm doing. I have MySQL View which I query (select *) as the tMySQLInput. That returns me a list of rows  {code, city, country } sorted by code I need to clean the city value in tMap and there are duplicates but I thought I'd use MySQL and set "code" as the primary key for the cleansed tMySQLOutput table as a way to ensure I end up with no duplicates in the Output table. Only rows where the city value doesn't have numeric values gets sent to tMySQLOutput.  UmeshR I'm not sure what you mean by committing changes on per record?

Comment: Can you post the schema of your source and target tables?

Comment: Updated the question to include the source and target schemas

Answer (score 0):

You can always try to do merge insert, which will update row on key duplicate.